# I want to rotate a link on Hover

Tags: html, css

the link is within the ul li structure.

```
<nav class="navCls1">
    <ul class="navigationLinkscls1">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The css for this is as below

```
.navigationLinkscls1 li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    //border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
}
.navigationLinkscls1 li a {
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    //border:1px solid green;
    padding:3px 20px 3px 20px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 11px #999999;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: .25s linear;
    -o-transition: .25s linear;
    transition: .25s linear;
}
.navigationLinkscls1 li a:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

But the code is not running . Please help. I am relatively new in HTML5,CSS3 and  i am working in the latest version of crome.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2XHN/)**

Comment: Could you add a link to jsFiddle or codepen so we can see the code (not?) working?

Answer (score 3):

Change
`.navigationLinkscls1 li a:hover`
to
`.navigationLinkscls1 li:hover`.

Css rotation doesn't work on `display: inline;` elements (and the 'a' element inherits this from the browser).

You could also add the code:

```
.navigationLinkscls1 li a{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, add display:inline-block to a:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gdb52/

```
.navigationLinkscls1 li a{
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
//border:1px solid green;
padding:3px 20px 3px 20px;
box-shadow:5px 5px 11px #999999;
color:#000000;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-block;

-webkit-transition:  .25s linear;
-moz-transition: .25s linear;
-o-transition:  .25s linear;
transition: .25s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector for your hover part: `.navigationLinkscls1 > li:hover`

A jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bQ7BG/